# Remove a DIV with a delay Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, delay, fade

this is my first question so forgive me if I don't apply the correct etiquette.

I have a javascript function that hides a div with a fade.

```
function fadeOut(cloudChatHide)
{
    "use strict";
    cloudChatHide.onclick = function()
        { 
            if(cloudChatHide.className)
                {
                cloudChatHide.className = '';
                } 
            else 
                {               
                cloudChatHide.className = 'fadeout';
                RemoveCloudChat();
                }
        };
}
```

However this code doesn't remove the DIV which is the RemoveCloudChat Function. Which looks like this:-

```
function RemoveCloudChat()
{
    "use strict";
    cloudChatHide.remove();
    cloudChatHide.className ='fadeout';
}
```

What I really want to do is fade the div automatically after a few seconds and then REMOVE it.

The reason I need to REMOVE the div from the window is that its an overlaid div and I need to access the content underneath the 'cloudChatHide' div.

Any help / instruction wouild be gratefully received as I am not the greatest Javascript developer.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep?noredirect=1&lq=1 can lead you into the right direction.

Comment: HI thanks for that, TBH I don't really understand whats written there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use JQuery, it will really simple, see following:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fadeout">I'LL DISAPPEAR IN 3 SECONDS</div>
</body>
  <script>
    function fadeOut()
    {
        $(".fadeout").fadeToggle(500, "swing",function(){
                  this.remove();
                });
    }

    var delay = 3000; //3 seconds
    setTimeout(fadeOut, delay);
  </script>
</html>
```

When the fade action is completed the div will be removed.
I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: HI thanks for your answer, however I want the DIV to be REMOVED after a DELAY but without it being clicked on. My original code handles the fade as it stands, what I want is 1. The DIV loads, 2. After a delay of say 5000 the DIV fades 3. then the div is removed and this must all happen without a click or any other interaction by the user. Thanks

Comment: Would you remove the div after a delay from when the page was loaded?

Comment: Yes, the page loads, the div appears then after a delay fades and then is removed, thats what I need. Thanks

Comment: Let me see if I can implement this BRB

Comment: Sorry - I didn't know I downvoted - how do I change that and upvote?

Comment: I fixed my downvote, I am sorry, I didn't mean to do that - I am new here.

Comment: Using jQuery just o fade an element is a bit exaggerated. oO

Comment: i agree with @Werner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS transitions to smoothly fade out the element and listen for the transitionend event to remove the element when the transition has finished.

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8r63rbxe/).

The transition is defined with this CSS:

```
div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

div.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

As soon as you add the fade-out class to a div it will smoothly reduce its opacity over a period of 1 second. This can be done with the following JavaScript, no jQuery required:

```
function fadeOutAndRemove(element) {
    element.classList.add('fade-out');
    element.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    });
}
```

If you want to start the fadeout transition automatically after a fixed delay you could call fadeOutAndRemove after a timeout

```
window.setTimeout(fadeOutAndRemove.bind(this, elementToHide), 3000)
```

or add a delay to the transition

```
transition: opacity 1s 3s;
```

and initalise the element with the fade-out class

```
<div class="fade-out"></div>
```

Comment: I think this is the acceptable answer. Well explained and no need for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant result from Alessandro Maglioccola

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fadeout">I'LL DISAPPEAR IN 3 SECONDS</div>
</body>
  <script>
    function fadeOut()
    {
        $(".fadeout").fadeToggle(500, "swing",function(){
                  this.remove();
                });
    }

    var delay = 3000; //3 seconds
    setTimeout(fadeOut, delay);
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without Jquery. I'm setting the opacity to 0 waiting 300ms using a `setTimeout` then do the reverse if it's already hidden.

```js
hideMe = function(selector, self) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (self.innerHTML == "Hide") {
    elem.classList.add("fade");
    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.classList.add("hidden");
      self.innerHTML = "Show";
    }, 300)
  } else {
    elem.classList.remove("hidden");
    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.classList.remove("fade");
      self.innerHTML = "Hide";
    }, 300)
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: steelblue;
}

#vanish {
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.redsquare {
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
  background: tomato;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<button onclick='hideMe("#vanish",this)'>Hide</button>
<div id="vanish" class="redsquare"></div>
<div class="header"></div>
```